# Django: prevent making migrations for some models

Tags: django, django-models

Django 3.2.6

I'd like some models not to made migrations at all.

Is it possible?

I tried:

**1.**
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#managed

class Meta:
managed = False

**2.**

```
 class PrimaryReplicaRouter:
     special_model_names = {'generalsettings', 'generalsettings', }

     def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
         if model_name in self.special_model_names:
             return False

         return True
```

It doesn't help: migrations are created.It doesn't migrate. But migrations become unnecessarily noisy.

I quote from here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/multi-db/#allow_migrate

> makemigrations always creates migrations for model changes, but if allow_migrate() returns False, any migration operations for the model_name will be silently skipped when running migrate on the db.

Well, I don't want to make migrations for some models. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you class, add following line:

```
class Meta:
    abstract = True
```

If any class Meta is abstract true, django doesn't create migration file for that models

Here you go for more details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#abstract

Comment: thank you for the answer. But this doesn't seem to help me as I need apps.get_model as well. But get_model doesn't find abstract models.

Comment: Yes, get_model doesnt find the abstract models, I guess you have existing table?

Comment: The project is a bit complicated. Anyway, I need get_model to work.

Comment: Hi, try option managed = False - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/options/#managed

Answer (score 0):

you must to delete in your file your models migration file before apply managed=False

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!